# How do I stop ruby environment from activating by default in iterm

Tags: ruby, environment

I recently installed ruby, and now every time I open a new terminal session I can see that the environment in active (See screenshot). I have already checked my .zshrc and .bash_profile files and couldn't find anything about ruby. [image]

Comment: How did you install Ruby?

Comment: But that's probably part of the shell snippet you're using (like oh-my-zsh or other), where is displaying your current ruby version. You should remove it from that place.